# Downloading files in ASP.net and SQL Server database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, webmatrix

I am working with WebMatrix and need help getting a user to click on a link which opens a PDF file and can view it using adobe reader. This file is uploaded on the database by the admin user on an asp.net web page.

Comment: What part are you having trouble with?  Have you coded anything?

Comment: I have being able to add a button to upload the file by the admin user. I'm having trouble displaying it for the regular user with a link. @ChrisLively Thanks!

Comment: We really need you to be *very* specific about the problem.  As it stands I can't tell if you don't know how to add a button to an aspx page, don't know how to query a database, don't know how to stream bytes from a db server to a browser, etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Storing, uploading and downloading files in ASP.NET and SQL Server database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985587/storing-uploading-and-downloading-files-in-asp-net-and-sql-server-database)

Comment: Here's a link to an article that walks you through the process http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/148/Save-And-Retrieve-Files-From-a-Sql-Server-CE-Database-with-WebMatrix